# Redirect Plugin Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, timer

I'm trying to create a Redirect timer plugin from all JS (JQuery) but for some reason its not updating the timer since I started using a different method:

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.redirect = function( options ) {  
   var settings = {
      'second' : '10'
    };
    var options=$.extend( settings, options );
    return this.each(function() {
    var o=options;
if(o.second!==false){
var Seconds = o.second;
}   });   };
  })( jQuery );
```

Note this is not the whole code but you can check out the whole code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/NVx8w/6/

The reason I didnt just post the code here is because I think that JS Fiddle is easier to edit with. Some people complain that I only give a link but note: "When you click the link it WILL give you a code in an edit"

At the moment it is messy and hard to read, but once I get the seconds to work correctly I can set everything up like its suppose to.(:

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a variable `Second` in this statement:

```
setTimeout("$('#re_message').hide();$('#redirect1').delay(50).fadeIn();", Second + 500);
```

when it should be `Seconds`. If you fix that the script will work. I recommend using Firebug (in Firefox) or Web Inspector in Safari/Chrome, the console in both those tools could've pointed you towards that issue within seconds. ;)